# Como gravar dados no webstorage sem substituir os dados já gravados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Eu criei um formulário e quando o usuário preencher esse formulário os dados sejam enviados para o webstorage local e de lá para uma tabela. Porém, sempre que gravo um dado no localstorage o dado anterior é substituído, é possível fazer com que os dados sejam enviados para essa tabela sem substituir os dados já existentes?
Obs.: Tem que ser somente com JQuery.

Comment: posta o código que você tá usando pra salvar os dados

Comment: Respondi uma pergunta similar a algum tempo.: [Local Storage - Sempre substitui o ultimo dado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160153/2363)

Answer (score 3):

Como já afirmaram em outras questões linkadas nos comentários, você precisa recuperar os dados existentes e acrescentar os novos. Como o web storage aceita apenas strings, a solução recomendada é usar serialização JSON para armazenar objetos, tal como arrays, em formato de string e depois recuperar o objeto, desserializando a string.

Uma solução específica para o seu caso, seria criar um objeto que encapsulasse o acesso necessário.

Como neste momento estou interessante em brincar com JS, fiz uma solução simples que você poderia usar como base, sem uso de bibliotecas como jQuery.

O objeto a seguir representa uma fila de submissões:

```
var submitQueue = (function() {
  var key = "my-form-queue";

  function fetchQueue() {
    var storedQueue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log('Recuperando... ', storedQueue);
    return storedQueue === null ? [] : JSON.parse(storedQueue);
  }
  function saveQueue(queue) {
    var serializedQueue = JSON.stringify(queue);
    console.log('Armazenando... ', serializedQueue);
    localStorage.setItem(key, serializedQueue);
  }

  return {
    push: function(obj) {
      var queue = fetchQueue();
      queue.push(obj);
      saveQueue(queue);
    },
    take: function() {
      var queue = fetchQueue();
      var first = queue.shift();
      saveQueue(queue);
      return first;
    },
    peek: function() {
      return fetchQueue();
    }
  }
})();
```

Ele contém 3 métodos:

1. `push`: coloca um elemento no final da fila.
2. `take`: retira o primeiro elemento da fila.
3. `peek`: permite recuperar uma cópia da fila.

Exemplo removendo o primeiro item da fila:

```
var proximoItem = submitQueue.take();
```

Exemplo adicionando um objeto à fila:

```
var nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value;
var data = document.querySelector('#data').value;
if (nome && data) {
  submitQueue.push({ name: nome, date: data });
}
```

Exemplo gerando o código HTML de uma lista com os itens:

```
var itensPendentes = submitQueue.peek();
var html = '<ol>';
itensPendentes.forEach(function(item) {
  html += '<li>Nome: ' + item.name + ', Data: ' +  item.date + '</li>';
});
html += + '</ol>';
```

Para geração de uma tabela simples, você pode usar um código similar. Num programa de verdade, onde geralmente as tabelas precisam ser melhor acabadas, sugiro usar um componente de tabela que aceita um array de objetos como fonte de dados.

### [Demonstração no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/ogbckcsu/)